# Why does the startup of TomEE fail?

Tags: bash, startup, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I downloaded [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/installing-tomee.html) zip file, extract it. The directory structure is like this:

```
apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1/
            - bin/
                -startup.sh
```

I added the following thing in my .bash_profile

```
export CATALINA_HOME=apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1
export PATH=$PATH:$CATALINA_HOME/bin
```

I run `source .bash_profile` .
Then, I run `startup.sh`
But I get error:

```
-bash: startup.sh: command not found
```

I then tried to run command `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` , 
I get error:

```
-bash: apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1/bin/startup.sh: No such file or directory
```

How to run startup.sh ?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, you forgot to add the `x`permission on the startup.sh and other scripts in the `bin` folder of the extracted TomEE archive.

This will solve it:

1. `chmod +x $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` (an other scripts as well)
2. `cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin/`
3. `./startup`

Also check that `export CATALINA_HOME=apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1` points to an absolute path - e.g. `/opt/apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1` - rather than only to the directory where you extracted the archive to.

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note the zip file format has no notion of Unix/Linux execution bits.  Any files you put in a zip will lose all information about if they were executable and what write permissions they had.  So unpacking from a zip, you will always have to set the *.sh files as executable.

If you download the tar.gz file, however, it can and does have the execution bits set properly.  It will unzip with all *.sh files properly executable with no action from you necessary.  You simply extract from the command line with the following:

```
tar xzvf apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1.tar.gz
./apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1/bin/startup.sh
```

Note also, the `./` at the beginning can avoid you having to put `apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1/bin/` in your `PATH` variable.  Not required, but can be convenient.